# Display last 3 High and last 3 Low

Tags: c#

I have a list of prices inside a `ConcurrentDictionary`.
Say I have 990 to 1010 and the current price is at 1000.

I have a loop that shows me

next closest buy 1001

next closest sell 999

the thing I'm stuck at is how can I get 2nd buy 1002 3rd buy 1003.. and 2nd sell 998 3rd buy 997..

this is how I get the top Price!

```
foreach (var eachPrice in Prices.Values) 
{
    if (eachPrice.Location > 1000) 
    {
        double itop = (eachPrice.Location - 1000) / 0.25;
        if (itop < ticksCeiling) 
        {
            ticksCeiling = itop;
            priceCeiling = eachPrice.Location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: I added a buy price sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand why you'd use a Dictionary, which is naturally an unordered device, when you want data that is some ordered distance away from a known value

Switch to using an ordered container to make your life easy, perhaps minimally by doing a `Values.OrderBy(v => v).ToArray()`, then you can find your 1000 at eg index 10 and know your next buy / sell is at 11 / 9 and so on

If you persist with the unordered collection you're going to have to ask repeatedly "what is the minimum value greater than X" for a buy and "what is the max value less than X" for a sell e.g. `Value.Where(v => v < 1000).Max()` and that gives 993, then for the next sell you need `Value.Where(v => v < 993).Max()` for the next one; very tedious and inefficient